# CQRS Write database

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

In our company we are developing a microservice based system and we apply CQRS pattern. In CQRS we separate Commands and Queries, because of that we have to develop 2 microservices. Currently I was assigned to enhance CQRS pattern to save events in a separate database (event sourcing). I understand that having a separate event database is very important but do we really need a separate Write Database? What is the actual use of the Write database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an event database, it is your Write database.  It is the system-of-record and contains the transactionally-consistent state of the application.

If you have a separate Read database, it can be built off of the event log in either a strongly-consistent or eventually-consistent manner.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct according to this,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs
"When used with the Event Sourcing pattern, the store of events is the write model, and is the official source of information."

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that having a separate event database is very important but do we really need a separate Write Database? What is the actual use of the Write database?

The purpose of the write database is to stand as your *book of record*.  The write database is the persisted representation that you use to recover on restart.  It's the synchronization point for all writes.

It's "current Truth" as your system understands it.

In a sense, it is the "real" data, where the read models are just older/cached representations of what the real data used to look like.

It may help to think in terms of an RDBMS.  When traffic is small, we can serve all of the incoming requests from a single database.  As traffic increases, we want to start offloading some of that traffic.  Since we want the persisted data to be in a consistent state, we can't offload the writes -- not if we want to be resolving conflicts at the point of the write.  But we can shed *reads* onto other instances, provided that we are wiling to admit some finite interval of time between when a write happens, and when the written data is available on all systems.

So we send all writes to the leader, who is responsible for organizing everything into the write ahead log; changes to the log can then be replicated to the other instances, which in turn build out local copies of the data structures used to support low latency queries.

If you look very carefully, you might notice that your "event database" shares a lot in common with the "write ahead log".

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't necessarily need a separate write database. The core of CQRS segregation is at the model (code) level. Going all the way to the DB might be beneficial or detrimental to your project, depending on the context.

As with many orthogonal architectural decisions surrounding the use of CQRS (Event Sourcing, Command Bus, etc.), the pros and cons should be considered carefully prior to adoption. Below some amount of concurrent access, separating read and write DBs might not be worth the effort.